# How to run Grunt tasks synchronously (programmatically)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs

I want a task that runs sub-tasks synchonously in a loop, and such loop is broken when a sub-task changes the value of a flag.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
grunt.registerTask('complexTask', 'Run sub-tasks synchronously.', function () {
    var value;
    do {
        // 'changeValueTask' task sets 'importantValue'
        grunt.task.run(['preTask', 'changeValueTask', 'postTask']);
        value = grunt.config('importantValue');
    } while (!value);
    // ... end task
});
```

What I want to get out of this is

- make sure that **each set of tasks** (`['preTask', 'changeValueTask', 'postTask']`) is run in order (sequentially)
- and the best way to break out of the loop

Is it possible to achive this?

Note: the closest thing I could find after some research was that Grunt allows to define that a given `task B` fails if `task A` is not done (with [grunt.task.requires](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.requires): `grunt.task.requires('A')`).

Comment: Don't use a loop, with a recursive approach you can do it asynchronously as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how we fixed it (following in the footsteps of Bergi's comment):

Instead of trying to explicitly loop and run tasks on Grunt, it is best to use the natural task-chaining mechanism of Grunt to ensure one task is executed after the other, like so

```
grunt.task.run(['preTask', 'changeValueTask', 'postTask']);
```

Assuming this, we used recursion at the end of each `postTask` to check if we need to run it again (by checking the `importantValue` flag) - we achieve this with a task on its own

```
grunt.task.run(['preTask', 'changeValueTask', 'postTask', 'taskCheck']);

grunt.registerTask('taskCheck', 'Recursive task.', function() {
  var value = grunt.config('importantValue');
  if (value) {
    // done... work with value
  } else {
    // keep running
    grunt.task.run(['preTask', 'changeValueTask', 'postTask', 'taskCheck']);
  }
});
```

As an improvement we can bootstrap this whole recursion on a task to avoid unnecessary cluttering and isolate this looping behavior:

```
grunt.registerTask('runValueTask', 'Bootstrap to start recursion.', function() {
  grunt.task.run(['preTask', 'changeValueTask', 'postTask', 'taskCheck']);
});

grunt.registerTask('taskCheck', 'Recursive task.', function() {
  var value = grunt.config('importantValue');
  if (value) {
    // done... work with value
  } else {
    // keep running
    grunt.task.run('runValueTask');
  }
});
```